For those who believe in the resurrection, what makes it different from these other extraordinary sightings?
Paul wrote that 500 people saw Jesus at once (1 Cor 15:6). If his recounting is true, it's obvious they saw something, but it's not clear to me why that thing couldn't have been a vague figure misinterpreted as Jesus.  Here are some similar events:

108 people saw the Virgin Mary appear at a waterfall and then to the adults of the group at Mass. Link Among the observers were doctors, psychologists, psychiatrists, engineers, and lawyers.

A second example comes from Cairo, Egypt in 1986, at a Coptic church.  Mary had appeared a number of times between 1983 and 1986.  Once she appeared on the roof, four Coptic bishops arrived to authenticate the vision.  They did indeed see her.  At other times she was seen by (non-Christian, obviously) Muslims. Link

During the supposed Miracle of Fatima, many people claimed to see the sun exhibit strange behavior, whirling toward the earth. Link

Betty Parris (age 9) and her cousin Abigail Williams (age 11), the daughter and the niece, respectively, of Reverend Samuel Parris, began to have fits described as "beyond the power of epileptic fits or natural disease to effect" by John Hale, the minister of the nearby town of Beverly. Link

Sixty-two pupils at the Ariel School aged between six and twelve said that they saw one or more silver craft descend from the sky and land on a field near their school. Some of the children claimed that one or more creatures dressed all in black then approached and telepathically communicated to them a message with an environmental theme, frightening them and causing them to cry. Several of them have maintained their account into adulthood. Link



The question is, basically, "How does believing in the resurrection of Jesus Christ differ from believing in these four examples of miraculous sightings of wondrous things, and of the appearances of the virgin Mary?"
The answer is very simple. It is that believing that the Son of God rose from the dead on the third day (whether one saw him alive after his crucifixion or not) is an essential part of being granted everlasting life by Christ (Mark 10:30b & John 1:4 & 3:15, 36).
Believing in any appearances of anything, or anyone else, never gives everlasting life to anybody.
Here are some words of Jesus, before he was crucified, to warn his followers about things that would deceive them:

"Take heed that no man deceive you. For many shall come in my name,
saying, I am Christ; and shall deceive many... And many false prophets
shall rise, and shall deceive many... Then if any man shall say unto
you, Lo, here is Christ, or there; believe it not. For there shall
arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall shew great signs
and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive
the very elect." Matthew 24:5, 11 & 23-24 A.V.
[In a vision of two symbolic 'beasts', the second one] "...exerciseth
all the power of the first beast before him, and causeth the earth and
them which dwell therein to worship the first beast, whose deadly
wound was healed. And he doeth great signs, so that he maketh fire
come down from heaven on the earth in the sight of men, and deceiveth
them that dwell on the earth by means of those signs..." Revelation
13:12-14 A.V.

Beware signs and wonders, in and of themselves. There is only one accompaniment that may authenticate them. When Jesus sent the twelve Apostles out, it was to "preach that men should repent. And they cast out many devils, and anointed with oil many that were sick, and healed them." Mark 6:12-13 A.V.
This means that any supernatural things seen or experienced on earth, which are not accompanied with preaching repentance, is not approved of by the risen Christ. When there is a genuine preaching of Christ, it is in order to get people down on their knees in repentance, to acclaim him as the only means of being pardoned by God for their sins, as they trust only in what he achieved on the cross, and by his resurrection, and acclaiming him as the only great high priest and mediator between God and men (Hebrews 7:25 & 9:11-16).
But, praise God, those who are given everlasting life by Christ do not need to have ever seen him with their eyes, or in any vision. That is why the Apostle John wrote his account of Jesus, writing:

"Then [Jesus] said to Thomas, Reach hither thy finger, and behold my
hands; and reach hither thy hand, and thrust it into my side: and be
not faithless, but believing. And Thomas answered and said unto him,
My Lord and my God. Jesus saith unto him, Thomas, because thou hast
seen me, thou hast believed: blessed are they that have not seen, and
yet have believed. And many other signs truly did Jesus in the
presence of his disciples, which are not written in this book. But
these are written, that ye might believe that Jesus is the Christ, the
Son of God; and that believing ye might have life through his name."
John 20:27-31 A.V. [Emphasis mine]

If what has already been written in God's word, by eyewitnesses, is not good enough for anybody, then nothing else ever shall be. To reiterate, the difference is that believing in the name of the living Christ gives life everlasting. Believing in anything else never will.

This doesn't seem to me to really address the question, which is how the sightings of Christ after His resurrection as such are different from these other miraculous sightings.

@jaredad  Outwardly, just going by audio-visual impressions, there may be difficulty for any multitude present to make the case for Christ's post-resurrection sightings being different in any important respect, but Christians know many Bible prophecies were made predicting exactly what happened to Christ during his life, through to his crucifixion and beyond to his resurrection and ascension. Prophecies, most made thousands of years in advance and recorded via inspiration of the Holy Spirit, are what make the difference; all the difference.


OP: Paul wrote that 500 people saw Jesus at once (1 Cor 15:6). If his recounting is true, it's obvious they saw something, but it's not clear to me why that thing couldn't have been a vague figure misinterpreted as Jesus [emphasis added]

From what I read, the question isn't about the gospel or Christ, but rather about knowing the difference between seeing paranormal events or spiritual visions and those who saw Jesus after the resurrection.  How do we know the difference?
The primary difference is prophecy with fulfilled prophecy versus personal or group visions.
There are no recorded prophecies that the vision of Jesus' mother would take place.  So, although it might be pious, believed, yet it could easily be false.
There are no recorded prophecies of aliens visiting earth, dropping coins.  As much as people may accurately recount their visions, these may easily be false.
In short, visions are simply at best, interesting perhaps, but are in no way salvific.
For Christ's resurrection, however, it was prophesied and believing it is salvific.

For you will not abandon my soul to Hades,
or let your Holy One see corruption. Acts 2:27, Psalm 49:15

The whole of Acts 2 outlines the prophecies of Christ's resurrection.
Additionally, the 500 sighting of Jesus is within the context of others within the 40 days from resurrection to ascension.

to Cephas, the 12, 500, James, apostles, Paul (1 Cor 15).

Were they all deluded?  James (brother of Jesus per the flesh) and Paul for example also did not believe Christ would be resurrected until after Christ appeared to them.
Moreover, Christ talked with them, ate with them, performed miracles again for them, and instructed them.  See John chapter 21.
Jesus told Thomas to touch Him, proving He was real.

Look at my hands and my feet. It is I myself! Touch me and see; a ghost does not have flesh and bones, as you see I have.” Luke 24:39

There is no sense in the OP visions that there was an actual real person being encountered in those visions.  To paraphrase Jesus, those visions cited are of ghosts.
So, to answer the OP, the difference is very clear on a number of points.
After the prophesied resurrection, Jesus appears to believers and non-believers, He talks, has a flesh and bone body that may be touched, eats, teaches, and ascends in bodily form to heaven.

Physical Encounters Versus "Sightings."There is a vast difference between alleged "sightings" (whether of Jesus or Mary or any saint) and the encounters of the Disciples with the resurrected Jesus!
What happened after the Resurrection of Jesus that was recorded, were not apparitions in the sky, appearances at a distance, or imagined cloud formations...nor images on a fried taco shell! (as happened in Mexico)
Jesus appeared physically---in person---to the Disciples, who by the way knew Jesus intimately, having traveled with Him for 3 1/2 years. And to establish beyond any doubt, Jesus interacted with them in an empirical method way.

That which was from the beginning, which we have heard, which we have seen with our eyes, which we have looked upon, and our hands have handled---of the Word of Life---(For the life was manifested and we have seen it, and bear witness, and show unto you that eternal life, which was with the Father, and was manifested unto us); that which we have seen and heard declare we unto you, that you may also have fellowship with us, and truly our fellowship is with the Father, and with His Son, Jesus Christ. (1 John 1:12-3)


The other disciples therefore said to him (Thomas), "We have seen the Lord!"But he said unto them, "Unless I shall see in His hands the print of the nails, and put my finger into the print of the nails, and thrust my hand into His side, I will not believe."...


And Jesus came and stood in the midst, and said, "Peace be unto you!"Then He said to Thomas, "Reach hither thy finger, and behold my hands; and reach hither thy hand, and thrust it into my side, and be not faithless, but believing.And Thomas said unto Him, "My Lord and my God!" (John 20:25-28)


After these things, Jesus showed himself again to the disciples at the Sea of Tiberias...As soon as they were come to land(after fishing) they saw a fire of coals there, and fish laid thereon and bread. Jesus said unto them, "Bring of the fish you have caught...And Jesus said to them, "Come and dine." And none of the disciples asked him, "Who are you?" knowing that it was the Lord! (John 21:1, 9-12)

Empirical InteractionA survey of the recordings about the Resurrection reveal that the Disciples interacted with Jesus in the physical realm.  These were interactions that were not apparitions seen at a distance, coming and fading in the ethreal realm!
And they were repeated to different people on different occasions with different actions performed at different locations and different times of the day:  Eating, drinking, cooking, touching, interactive conversations, traveling, multiple witnessing (to Mary, disciples, Apostles, and Paul, et altera)

Until the day in which Jesus was taken up, after that he through the Holy Spirit had given commandments unto the Apostles whom He had chosen; To whom He also showed Himself alive after His passion by many infallible proofs, being seen by them forty days, and speaking of the things pertaining to the Kingdom of God. (Acts 1:2-3)

Many have given Thomas, the dubious title of "doubting Thomas", but that is not a biblical title. If we were to name him, it would be more appropriate to call him, "Empirical Thomas." This is because Thomas removed the knowledge about the Resurrection out of the realm of speculation into the realm of "scientific fact."  Observable, repeatable, verifiable These actions of Thomas has forever removed the alibis of modernists and excuses of atheists given to the Scientific Method, who claim to only accept things that can only be "empirically proven." Thomas did us all a favor! What he observed was done in the presence of many witnesses.
Resulting BenefitsWhile some who have seen apparitions claim to have been healed, inspired, etc., the resulting consequence of the Resurrection of Jesus was the promise of the Holy Spirit---and with that "outpouring", the dispensing of the supernatural, fantastic Charismatic gifts upon the Church congregations: Gift of healing, Discerning of spirits, prophesying, casting out demons, empowered evangelism, etc)  These were all experienced on the Day of Pentecost according to the amazing prophecy of Joel!

Let not your heart be troubled...In My Father's house are many mansions...I go to prepare a place for you. And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again, and receive you unto Myself...I will pray the Father, and He shall give you another Comforter...even the Spirit of truth...the Comforter, which is the Holy Spirit...will teach you all things, and bring to your remembrance whatsoever I have said. (John 14:1-26; see also Acts 3, 1 Corinthians 12-14)


And being assembled together with them, commanded them that they should not depart from Jerusalem, but wait for the Promise of the Father, which you have heard from Me.For John truly baptized with water; but you shall be baptized with the Holy Spirit not many days hence. (Acts 1:4-5)

The established Resurrection of Jesus also has given Believers Hope beyond the grave. The physical resurrection ensures a "physical resurrection" of believers, and gives them hope---with an accompanying perseverance---that propels them through this adverse life. It is doubtful that a mere apparition would give this much assurance.

Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who according to His abundant mercy has begotten us again unto a living hope by the Resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead, to an inheritance incorruptible, and undefiled, and that fades not away, reserved in heaven for you... (1 Peter 1:3-4)

The Disciples of Jesus---the resurrected Jesus---were so convinced of the actual resurrection that they went throughout the Roman Empire preaching the Good New...and turned the world upside down! And they did this at the risk of persecution and martyrdom! No apparition indeed!

Rene Descartes argued in Meditations on First Philosophy that the cause must always be greater than the effect, or "no effect can have a greater amount of reality than its cause". The death and resurrection of Jesus Christ is the cause which permits Mary (if these cited phenomena are factual) to visit the faithful and bestow blessings. That is the difference between Christ's miraculous rising from the tomb and Mary's appearances.
Consider Job. That man experienced great loss and suffering, but retained his faith in God. That suffering became a channel by which God could pour wisdom into Job's mind and heart. In the Bible, God delivered to Job a speech longer than any other single address to any other person and possibly a place as the first book in the Bible to be written.
By this principle, if a person should experience a greater loss than Job and respond in faith, then God would surely bestow upon them even greater blessings. Consider the words of the prophet Simeon that he spoke to Mary:

34 And Simeon blessed them, and said unto Mary his mother, Behold,
this child is set for the fall and rising again of many in Israel; and
for a sign which shall be spoken against;
35 (Yea, a sword shall pierce through thy own soul also,) that the
thoughts of many hearts may be revealed. (Luke 2:34-35)

At the foot of the cross, Mary's soul was pierced. She saw her beloved son Jesus die an unjust death. By this event, apart from Jesus losing his own life, Mary bore the greatest loss that anyone in history has ever suffered, for Jesus is infinite, eternal and all-loving, the one who gave the most, therefore is worth the most. We know from Scripture that Mary did not abandon her faith or leave the church after this happened. Therefore, she must by this principle have received a far greater blessing than even Job, which she is authorized and empowered to share with the church. Yet it is Jesus' self-sacrifice that created this situation and so as great as Mary's faith is and as great as are the blessings she has showered upon believers, the gift of eternal life is greater still, and that is what Jesus gave us all, even Mary.

Prophecy fulfillment
Ezekiel 37:12

12 Therefore prophesy and say to them: ‘This is what the Sovereign Lord says: My people, I am going to open your graves and bring you up from them; I will bring you back to the land of Israel.

Matthew 27:52-53

52 and the graves were opened; and many bodies of the saints who had fallen asleep were raised;
53 and coming out of the graves after His resurrection, they went into the holy city and appeared to many.

None of the other extra-ordinary sights mentioned have a biblical prophecy about them.

Resurrection is also a teaching of Jesus/bible

John 5:21
John 11:25
Romans 4:17
etc (not exhaustive list)

Mary appearing, strange sun behavior, extreme fits, and supposed alien/foreign visits are not necessarily biblical teachings.

Oh, Doubting 'Christian Montgomery', must you see the resurrected Jesus and each Church accepted Apparition, putting your fingers in every Stigmata of them before you Believe?
As Testified in Scripture, Jesus' resurrected Being was very intimately experienced by all the Apostles, and arguably progressively less so by those that may not have known anything about Him and His earlier ministries, miracles, and teachings, yet witnessed Him and-or His Ascension.
So, the significant difference being that Scriptural Testimony as the highest Authority, where Catholic Affirmation of acceptance of any specific Apparition is not a required by Faith to be Believed, but Prudence suggests that it should be.

That Alien encounter with a Globalist [political] message (we now suffer daily along with the loss of Institutional Trust,) out of some distant African place, has that 'feel' of those old News of World cheap rags that report on Alien fetus found in a Squash in some impossible to reach place deep in Soviet Union. Since Elvis is still being seen and engaging people - we are told by similar publications - perhaps someone might ask him about Aliens mind-twisting abuse of children for Globalists goals.

Sadly, it seems that - by my count - 3 Answers of (-1) score, out of 12 Answers to 12 Questions here has somehow blocked my ability to Answer questions. So, the moderators anti-Catholics, and GramerNazis will not have me to kick-around for a while.

The blocking is an automatic mechanism, and it isn't the moderators that are voting your answers down. Other readers downvoted because of your own failure to accept and correct the fact that some of your answers aren't very informative, useful, or relevant to the question that was asked. ¶Answering questions on all Stack Exchange sites is a learning experience in itself, and you seem not to be learning how to answer questions. You've made a minor edit to one answer and left the other 11 unchanged. The purpose of comments is to help you improve the answer, yet yours remain unchanged.
